# Is the ratio between a bloom filter intersection and a bloom filter union equal to that of their original sets?

Tags: data-structures, bloom-filters

Given two sets, S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub>, and their corresponding bloom filters, BF<sub>1</sub> and BF<sub>2</sub>, is there a way to prove that |BF<sub>1</sub> ∩ BF<sub>2</sub>|/|BF<sub>1</sub> ∪ BF<sub>2</sub>| = |S<sub>1</sub> ∩ S<sub>2</sub>|/|S<sub>1</sub> ∪ S<sub>2</sub>| (we can assume both bloom filters are generated using the same set of hash functions)? If not, is there a way to approximate one given the other?

Comment: @D.W. I think you may have misread the question: both bloom filters being generated using the same hash functions is an assumption, not a question. Given this assumption, I am asking whether or not the given ratios are equal (I suppose I am looking for a proof of this statement and have edited the question accordingly).

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the edit!  Next questions: (1) What does $|BF|$ mean?  Can you define that notation?  Is it the number of bits set in the bloom filter $BF$?  (2) Have you tried to prove or disprove this?  Have you worked through some small examples?  I think if you work through some very small examples (let's say, where $|S|_1=|S|_2=1$) you should quickly be able to answer your first question....